# Is this php file (with an image) being loaded every time the page is visited?

Tags: ajax, image, fancybox

I wanted the images to be loaded only when the user click the link:

```
<a id="showcase1" href="showcase/showcase1.php"><img src="images/showcase1t.png"/></a>
```

So I placed the images in another php file and call the using ajax and `fancybox`:

**showcase1.php:**

```
<div id="inline1">
 <img src="images/showcase1.png"/>
 <a href="http://studyatbest.com">studyatbest.com</a>
</div>
```

I'm not very familiar with ajax.

Is the image from `showcase1.php` being loaded every time someone visit the page. Or just when I click the anchor link?

(The problem is that I'm not sure if `showcase1.php and the image inside the file` are: 1. being loaded but just not displayed. 2. or being loaded in the right moment I click the anchor link.)